# How to add a subtitle to an HLS playlist using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I have a video (`video.mp4`) and a subtitle file (`subtitle.srt`).

I'm trying to use FFmpeg to generate a VoD HLS playlist with 3 different resolutions for the video; and I also want the subtitle file to turn into segmented `.vtt` files.

I've tried the following command, but it doesn't work, it gives me a "Conversion failed!" message without any further information:

```sh
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i subtitle.srt \
-preset slow -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 \
-map 0 -map 0 -map 0 -map 1 \
-s:v:0 640x360 -c:v:0 h264 -b:v:0 500k \
-s:v:1 854x480 -c:v:1 h264 -b:v:1 1000k \
-s:v:2 1280x720 -c:v:2 h264 -b:v:2 2000K \
-c:a copy -c:s webvtt \
-f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2" \
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 -hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_allow_cache 1 -start_number 1 \
-hls_segment_filename "output/hls/%v/seg-%d.ts" output/hls/%v/index.m3u8
```

I'm struggling to find any useful information in FFmpeg docs or anywhere else regarding how subtitles can be added to an HLS playlist. What should the command be like exactly? What am I missing in mine?

Comment: For anyone visiting this question in the future and struggling with a similar problem: Use Shaka Packager instead of FFmpeg for this task, it's WAY easier to work with, and a saner tool overall, FFmpeg is just pure headache, I ended up opting for Shaka Packager and I'm not going back.

Comment: hello there, did you workout this command? for me it still says
`[hls @ 000002689df607c0] Same elementary stream found more than once in two different variant definitions #0 and #1
[hls @ 000002689df607c0] Variant stream info update failed with status ffffffea
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:5 --`

Comment: @jeff No unfortunately I gave up on FFmpeg and started using Shaka Packager. Take a look at my previous comment.

Comment: i see, thanks for replying anyway. Btw if you are interested, I got your command working with this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/mfybas/comment/gssvbsg/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3
I am not sure if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation isn't great, but see near the bottom of the section for `-var_stream_map`. You need to add a mapping for the subtitles to the relevant variant stream groups.

So your example above will become:

```
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,s:0 v:1,a:1,s:0 v:2,a:2,s:0"
```

If you wish, you can set the subtitle group name by appending `,sgroup=examplegroupname`.

Finally, there is an undocument option `hls_subtitle_path` which allows you to set the subtitle manifest name (which defaults to the main m3u8 name plus `_vtt.m3u8`.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know who downvoted your answer. Weird. They downvoted my question too. I have no idea why. Anyways, I've been trying to work with `-var_stream_map` ever since I posted the question but not only the documentation is awful, the error messages are cryptic as well. You mentioned the `hls_subtitle_path` option. Thanks for that. Is there also an option to set the name of the subtitle segments? It defaults to the main m3u8 file name + the segment number (e.g. `playlist2.vtt`) which is not nice. Plus, is there anywhere I can find the list of the undocumented options?

Comment: Unfortunately, for subtitle segment names, it looks like `hls_segment_filename` is not applied, and there appears to be no equivalent option which looks like an oversight :-(
All available options can be shown using `ffmpeg -h muxer=hls`, although the documentation isn't great for some options. If you can understand C, the source at https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/hlsenc.c is helpful.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward Oh such a bummer! But thanks so much for your help. Greatly appreciated.